# Why use inline list items for tabs?

Tags: html, css

When making tabs on a website, I always used an unordered list with inline-block list items.  Why is this generally considered the correct way over something like a few divs with the same inline-block display setting?

```
.tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
}

<ul class='tabs'>
    <li>Tab one</li>
    <li>Tab two</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

vs

```
.tabs > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class="tabs">
   <div>Tab 1</div>
   <div>Tab 2</div>
   ...
</div>
```

I realize this question can be subjective, but I think there exists an objective answer.

Comment: So it boils down to semantics, I knew there would be an objective answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unstylized content:

When stripped of the CSS, the `<ul>` format will give the viewer a better understanding of the purpose of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

That gives it more semantic meaning and is the perfect element for navbars and tabs..divs per se don't carry any semantic meaning with them..

Comment: I don't think there's anything more semantic than a div-ider for a tab.

Comment: I suppose that's fair

Answer (score 1):

semanticaly, ideologically, and when viewing as unstyled content, unordered list is more close to what you're trying to achieve than just bunch of divs.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5, this is even the only way you should go, because your list should be included inside a `<nav>` element. See [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav). So the answer is, for semantic. With a list, the items are linked to each other, which improves accessibility.